# componentDidUpdate get triggers at multiple screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux-thunk

Im using `redux-thunk` for API calling. While response coming back from the server, I catch them at `componentDidUpdate` with the simple validation as follow

```
async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
     if (this.props.successCalling && !prevProps.successCalling) {
          executeSomeCode();
     }
}
```

The problem is, I'm having 2 same validation at 2 different screens, when responses are back from server `componentDidUpdate` both the validations are met. Hence it run both the `executeSomeCode()` at both different screens. How am I suppose to handle this kind of scenario?

Comment: from where do you call that service ? from each screen ?

Comment: both the screens are calling the same API, but with different parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While calling the service for a particular screen you can use a class level variable which can act as a switch like -  true/ false, where this.switch will be set to false initially. on calling the service just update that class variable to true and add that variable to the if logic check as mentioned in the above example.

This way every screen will have its own switch which can be used to determine if the service call is for that particular screen or not.

Comment: Instead of doing what you suggest to have switch case, I came up with another solution (which inspired by your solution) I pass extra parameter to my API method and append the parameter in my return result. Hence method in didUpdate can do the logic check. So I'll consider your suggestion as my answer (: